# Recursively inputting a row in a math array

Tags: macros

What may be a neat way of recursively inputting an arbitrary number of rows in a math array? In particular, suppose if I write

`\mycommand{A/B, C/D}`

then I get

`\begin{array}{l} A \mapsto B \\ C \mapsto D\end{array}`

whereas if I simply write `\mycommand{A/B}` then I just get

`\begin{array}{l} A \mapsto B \end{array}`

I already tried this with

`\newcommand*{\mycommand}[1]{
  \begin{array}{l} \foreach \xx/\yy in {#1} {
    \xx \mapsto \yy \\
  } \end{array}
}`

but then I realized, I'm having problems with `\\` for each new row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't process rows with a `\foreach` cycle in that way. There are two reasons for this:

1. every cycle is processed in a group
2. doing it in an `array` cell can't work anyway, because cells form groups.

Here is an `expl3` implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{O{c}m}
 {
  \eric_mycommand:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\tl_new:N \l__eric_array_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \eric_mycommand:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__eric_array_tl
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \__eric_process_entry:w ##1 \q_stop
   }
  \begin{array}[#1]{l@{}l}
  \l__eric_array_tl
  \end{array}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__eric_process_entry:w #1 / #2 \q_stop
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__eric_array_tl { #1 & {} \mapsto #2 \\ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

x $\mycommand{A/B}$ y

x $\mycommand[t]{A/B, C/D, E/F}$ y

\bigskip

x $\mycommand{A/B, C/D, E/F}$ y

\end{document}
```

[image]

The optional argument is used for the vertical alignment of the `array`.

---

With `\foreach` you can do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\providecommand{\expandonce}[1]{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}

\newcommand\mycommand[1]{%
  \gdef\mycommandtemp{}%
  \foreach \xx/\yy in {#1}{%
    \xdef\mycommandtemp{\expandonce{\mycommandtemp}%
      \expandonce{\xx} & {} \noexpand\mapsto \expandonce{\yy} \noexpand\\}}
  \begin{array}{l@{}l}
    \mycommandtemp
  \end{array}}

\begin{document}

x $\mycommand{A/B}$ y

\bigskip

x $\mycommand{A/B, C/D, E/F}$ y

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is really good. Thanks! For now I prefer the `\foreach` code since I understand how it runs. However, I am impressed about the first one on how you thought of the alignment! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

An attempt without packages:

(update: this method is quite similar to `egreg` second one with `\foreach` and uses a token register rather than a temporary macro; I provide also a second method not doing any assignments, now that I have understood that a `\\` just before the final `\end{array}` is ok, if there is nothing in-between (not even a relax)).

```
\documentclass{article}

% first method:

\newtoks\ERICtoks
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ERICarray [1]{\ERICarray@ #1,\ERICarray/,}
\def\ERICarray@  #1/#2,{\ERICtoks={#1\mapsto #2}\ERICarray@@}
\def\ERICarray@@ #1/#2,%
    {\ifx\ERICarray#1\ERICarray@end\else
     \ERICtoks=\expandafter{\the\ERICtoks\\#1\mapsto#2}\fi\ERICarray@@}
\def\ERICarray@end #1\fi\ERICarray@@%
    {\fi\begin{array}{l}\the\ERICtoks\end{array}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
One line
$\ERICarray{A/B}=
\begin{array}{l}
  A\mapsto B
\end{array}$

Two lines
$\ERICarray{A/B, C/D}=
\begin{array}{l}
  A\mapsto B\\
  C\mapsto D
\end{array}$

Five lines
$\ERICarray{A/B,C/D, E/F,G/H ,  K/L}=
\begin{array}{l}
  A\mapsto B\\ C\mapsto D\\ E\mapsto F\\ G\mapsto H\\ K\mapsto L
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image: eric arrays]

```
% second method (no assignments, only delimited macros):
\newcommand*\ERICarray [1]{\begin{array}{l}
                           \ERICarrayLOOP #1,\end{array}\ERICarrayCLEANUP/,}
\def\ERICarrayLOOP #1/#2,{#1\mapsto#2\\\ERICarrayLOOP}
\def\ERICarrayCLEANUP\mapsto\\\ERICarrayLOOP{}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how you guys can easily program something like this. I'm jealous!

Comment: @Eric I am jealous of `egreg` too... ;-) and perhaps it is time I learn `LaTeX3`... (after my vacations, though)